# Search Particular Word in PDF by using C# and SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, pdf, text

I'm developing an C# application that will search a particular word in a list of  PDF files. 
The result should return: 
1) The PDF files where the word was found;
2) Those PDF's page where the word was found; 
3) Bring a part of the text where the word was found and highlight that word.

**I have found in my research some solutions described below:**
- Insert the PDF file into the SQL Server as varbinary and use SQL SERVER's full-text search;
- Use SQL SERVER's Filetables resource and SQL SERVER's full-text search;
- Upload the PDF file to a physical folder and use ITextSharp plugin to accomplish the tasks.

Could someone that has experience with this, how can I do this ?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to find some way to either read the PDF in real time, or store its text in the database before the search request.  You can't use SQL full text directly on PDF content, because the textual content of the PDF is sometimes encoded as binary data.

For your requirement, you'd have to build a table that has a row for each distinct PDF page you want to reference, if you're going to use the database approach.

Comment: What about SQL SERVER's Filetables ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ff929144(v=sql.120).aspx

Comment: Filetables just allows sql server to look at regular files stored in a folder.  They're still binaries whether they're dumped in a table as varbinary, or by way of filetables.  Using filetables gives no advantage to the "core" requirement, which is to DECODE the files to extract the text.